# ¿De qué manera debo escribir en un texto en castellano un nombre que proviene del ruso? (Tildes)

Tags: traducción, ortografía, extranjerismos

Estoy escribiendo un trabajo que trata sobre los espacios de Sóbolev, debido a Serguéi Sóbolev, que en ruso se escribe Серге́й Льво́вич Со́болев.

La pregunta es bastante simple, ¿Debo escribirlos con tildes o sin ellas? Es decir,

> ¿Debo escribir "Espacio de Sóbolev" o "Espacio de Sobolev"?

Una simple búsqueda en google muestra que no hay un criterio uniforme para escribirlos. Por ejemplo, la Wikipedia ([Entrada en Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espacio_de_S%C3%B3bolev)) los escribe con tildes, pero en otros ámbitos (incluso académicos) lo he visto escrito sin tildes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

El DRAE dice que sí, que deben acentuarse:

> **6. Acentuación de palabras extranjeras**
>
> **6.2. Palabras extranjeras adaptadas**. Las palabras de origen extranjero ya incorporadas al español o adaptadas completamente a su
>   pronunciación y escritura, incluidos los nombres propios, deben
>   someterse a las reglas de acentuación de nuestro idioma: béisbol, del
>   ingl. baseball; bidé, del fr. bidet; Milán, del it. Milano; Icíar, del
>   eusk. Itziar. **Las transcripciones de palabras procedentes de lenguas
>   que utilizan alfabetos no latinos, incluidos los nombres propios, se
>   consideran adaptaciones y deben seguir, por tanto, las reglas de
>   acentuación: glásnost, Tolstói, Taiwán.**

Fuente: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=OZrK0vx4MD66pYPK8X%7CAdwesaq4ND64VT09xQ