# ¿Es correcto mantener "de" y "el" separados en algún caso?

Tags: gramática, contracciones

Estoy leyendo "El maestro y Margarita", de Mijaíl Bulgákov ([¡los nombres transcritos de otros alfabetos se acentúan!](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16916/1674)).

En él hay una construcción que me ha parecido incorrecta:

> Naturalmente, los nuevos inquilinos del condenado apartamento también
>   fueron protagonistas **de el diablo** sabe qué manejos.

¿Lo es? ¿Hay algún caso en el que sea válido? Yo tenía entendido que solamente lo es cuando lo que viene a continuación es un nombre propio, del tipo "soy de El Salvador". Pero este no es el caso.

Comment: Nótese que pregunto por la validez de esta frase. Ahora bien, y ya que estamos, si alguien quiere dar una referencia general será más que bienvenida.

Comment: Curioso, si te paras a pensarlo parece que suena mejor si pronuncias "de + el" separado en este caso. La frase es _fueron protagonistas de algo_, siendo _algo_ una oración de relativo, en este caso _el diablo sabe qué manejos_. Si dices _fueron protagonistas del diablo_, parece que la oración de relativo se diluye y que cambia un poco el significado.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

En este caso me parece correcto.  Es evidente que hay una pausa, aunque brevísima, porque la locución «el diablo sabe qué manejos» no es parte íntegra de la oración principal, sino un elemento exclamatorio nominal, y sin la pausa se lo entendería mentalmente así al escucharlo:

```
fueron protagonistas del diablo sabe qué manejos
  |         |         |    |      |
  |         |         |    |      ^ verbo con sujeto… ¿¿??
  |         |         |    ^ objeto del preposición «de»
  |         |         ^ locución preposicional que modifica «protagonistas»
  |         ^ predicado nominal que corresponde a «los inquilinos» 
  ^ verbo con sujeto «los inquilinos»
```

Es un caso curioso, porque normalmente se trata de no escribir la contracción pero sí pronunciarla, pero en este caso creo que como ni se la pronunciaría, escribirla sin contracción sería lo más adecuado.  Quizás si el autor hubiese puesto la locución así, no habría pregunta alguna:

> … fueron protagonistas de ¡el diablo sabe qué manejos!

Answer (score 10):

A guifa le interesará saber que [su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17122/12637) acaba de ser avalada por el señor Pérez-Reverte. Como no me convenció [la respuesta de la RAE](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17164/12637), probé a escribir al maestro en Twitter. En [este enlace](https://twitter.com/charliealejo/status/745330797058605056) podéis ver mi consulta y sus respuestas, las cuales transcribo a continuación.

> **Pérez-Reverte:** En este caso, el uso separado es correcto. La frase "el diablo sabe que manejos" tiene consistencia propia. Otra cosa sería hablar de "los manejos del diablo".
>
> **Yo:** Muchísimas gracias, la RAE nos respondió que era incorrecto. ¡Le agradezco sinceramente habernos dado una segunda opinión!
>
> **Pérez-Reverte:** Pues con todo el respeto para la RAE, de la que formo parte, quien le respondió a eso se ha columpiado. Si vuelve a comunicarse, dígaselo y dele una colleja de mi parte. Un saludo.

Comment: ¡Uauuu!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Yo <3 Pérez-Reverte

Answer (score 9):

[Esta excepción](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=del) me ha sorprendido incluso a mí:

> Si en un enunciado coinciden dos secuencias consecutivas de la preposición y el artículo, se recomienda realizar la contracción solo en la segunda: *«Tasan el valor de la mercadotecnia por encima de el del marco institucional»* (*Excélsior* [Méx.] 1.11.96).

Más información en la *[Nueva gramática](http://www.rae.es/recursos/gramatica/nueva-gramatica)*, apartado [14.3h](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wncgkDzqmUlzyFzI).

Comment: Es una de estas cosas que no notas, pero para mí, `...encima del del marco...` suena horrible :)

Comment: Curiosísimo caso que se resolvería fácilmente si se permitiera utilizar los paréntesis matemáticos: _Tasan el valor de la mercadotecnia por encima de (el del marco institucional)_. Así quedaría claro cuál es la parte relativa.

Answer (score 5):

Este tipo de cosas siempre las acabo [consultando a la RAE](http://www.rae.es/consultas-linguisticas/formulario), ya que suelen responder en el mismo día. Sin embargo, para esta consulta se han tomado su tiempo. La respuesta ha sido la que transcribo a continuación:

> En relación con su consulta, nos complace remitirle a la última edición de la *Ortografía de la lengua española* (RAE y ASALE, 2010; [págs. 562-564](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=UeHIlWSjSgNNjdqZ)). Según lo que allí se indica, en el ejemplo que somete a nuestra consideración, el artículo ***el*** debió unirse con la preposición ***de***, formando la contracción *del* (*de + el = del*): *Naturalmente, los nuevos inquilinos del condenado apartamento también fueron protagonistas **del** diablo sabe qué manejos*. En esta oración, los inquilinos fueron ALGO (*protagonistas **del** diablo sabe qué manejos*), por lo que la construcción que se inicia con la contracción *del* (*diablo...*) es un complemento del nombre que determina a *protagonistas*. Como se observa, el significado no se ve afectado de ninguna manera.

Me resulta muy curioso que, en este caso, estoy más de acuerdo con lo expresado por guifa en [su respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17122/12637) que con lo afirmado por la RAE.

Comment: Bueno, en todo caso son recomendaciones, como el apartado enlazado dice, la recomendación de decir «de el del» no se ha usado en el registro culto. Quizás se podría defender el espacio en nuestro caso por decir que *el diablo* es un nombre propio aunque no se escriba con mayúscula.

Comment: @guifa me estoy haciendo fan del Ngram. En el registro culto [sí se ha usado pero ha ido decayendo](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=de+el+del&year_start=1720&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cde%20el%20del%3B%2Cc0) su uso hasta estar hoy ya desaparecido. Interesante lo de _el diablo_ como nombre propio, desde luego esta pregunta está dando mucho más debate del que parecía en un principio.

Comment: @guifa yo creo que el traductor optó por separar precisamente por eso, por considerar _el diablo_ un todo, como si habláramos de _El Salvador_ o similares.

Answer (score 4):

Parece que no es correcto.

Transcribo del *Diccionario de Dudas y Dificultades de la Lengua Española* de Manuel seco:

> Cuando la forma el va precedida de las preposiciones a y de, se
>   producen las contracciones al y del, no solo en la pronunciación, sino
>   también en la escritura: AL salir DEL colegio. Si el se escribe con
>   mayúscula por formar parte de determinados nombres propios (—> 6), la
>   contracción no se suele realizar en la escritura, pero sí en la
>   pronunciación: El monasterio de El Escorial, /del-
>   -eskoriál/; Fueron a El Ferrol, /al-ferról/.

Comment: ¡Gracias! ¿Podrías añadir referencia al diccionario, si es que existe virtualmente?

Comment: Que yo sepa no se puede consultar en Internet. ISBN: 9788423994250

Comment: Ah vale, gracias pues por tomarte el tiempo de copiarlo del libro... ¡y bienvenido a [spanish.se], que creo que no te lo había dicho!

Comment: No hay versión en Internet pero si existe en versión pdf de la cual lo copié.  

Gracias por la bienvenida. Nunca se me ha dado muy bien la lengua pero últimamente ha despertado mi interés. Aquí se aprende sobre todo leyendo las respuestas e intentando aportar algo.

Comment: @fedorqui [Aquí](https://es.scribd.com/doc/151700987/RAE-Seco-Manuel-Diccionario-de-dudas-y-dificultades-de-la-lengua-espanola) hay una versión virtual disponible de forma gratuita y con opción a descarga con pago, aunque no sé si será igual a la impresa. Este fragmento es el punto 4 de la página 177.

Comment: @Yay ¡gracias! Pensé que se podría encontrar de piratilla, qué bueno que haya una versión legal. La he añadido a las referencias de [What are some good online resources we can use?](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/a/84/1674)