# ¿Existe alguna regla gramatical que indique que "Parece yo" sea incorrecto?

Tags: gramática

En una charla familiar, alguien dijo, refiriéndose a otra persona: "*Parece (ser) yo.*"

En un primer momento, a todos nos pareció, si no incorrecto, al menos inusual. Sería, desde luego, mucho más común decir: "Se parece a mí" (o tal vez "Parezco yo", aunque mi impresión es que esta forma busca viabilizar gramaticalmente el semánticamente más apropiado: "(Una tercera persona) Parece yo"). Y, ni hablar, comenzaron a surgir otras posibles monstruosidades como: "Pareces yo", "Parezco tú". Con la tercera persona y con nombres se torna más aceptable: "Parezco él",  "Parezco Juan", "Parece María". Entonces la restricción pareciera centrarse en utilizar como predicativo los pronombres de primera y segunda persona.

Existe una tendencia -- si no una regla estricta -- a utilizar los pronombres en caso objetivo y los nombres personales precedidos por "a" en construcciones de este tipo, pero en ese caso se utilizaría el verbo pronominal "parecerse". No encontré nada en la Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española sobre el verbo "parecer" al respecto -- sólo alguna mención general a que los grupos nominales tienen un uso restringido como atributos de verbos copulativos, y la ausencia de cualquier ejemplo como los que mencioné más arriba.

Answer (score 5):

Según el [Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=seEVswKc5D6y2K5WFZ):

> Los pronombres personales tónicos son aquellos que pueden funcionar como sujeto (*TÚ sabrás*), como atributo (*Los culpables son ELLOS*) o como término de preposición (*Mi hermano vendrá con NOSOTROS*).

Sería correcto, entonces, decir "parece YO", si *yo* fuera un atributo y *parece* funcionara como verbo copulativo. (Solo hay atributo cuando hay verbo copulativo, más abajo se aclara). De hecho, *parece* es uno de los pocos verbos copulativos del español: ser, estar y parecer.

Entonces, respuesta corta, no, no habría error.

Pero el verbo "parecer" no siempre es copulativo. De hecho [tiene dos formas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=parecer) que son gramatical y semánticamente diferentes (en realidad son más de dos):

1. Cuando significa "ser similar a algo o alguien" es una forma *pronominal*, es decir, siempre va acompañada de un pronombre átono: **se** parece, parecer**se**, **me** parezco... Este verbo es **predicativo**, vale decir, *es el verbo el que predica*, el que indica la acción o el estado del sujeto. (Y los verbos predicativos no tienen atributo)
2. Cuando significa "dar la impresión de algo" es una forma no pronominal, vale decir, no va con pronombre átono. Por ejemplo *ella parece mirarme* o *pareces emocionado*. Este verbo es **copulativo**, es decir, *no es el verbo el que predica*, sino que una estructura llamada *atributo* es la que indica la acción o el estado del sujeto. (En este caso, "mirarme" y "emocionado" son atributos).

Entonces, si quieres usar el verbo "parecer" para indicar que alguien guarda semejanza contigo mismo, debes decir ***se parece a mí***, con pronombre **se**. Y en este caso no puedes usar "yo" como complemento directo, porque, como cito arriba, los pronombres tónicos no sirven para eso, sólo funcionan como sujeto, atributo o término de preposición.

Queda entonces preguntarse si al decir "parece yo" estás realmente tratando de decir alguna otra cosa distinta a "él tiene parecido conmigo". Porque, ya dijimos, si estás diciendo eso entonces la forma correcta es "se parece a mí".

Para considerar "parecer" como verbo copulativo tendríamos que observar que *solo aporta al predicado el modo y el tiempo*, mientras que el grueso del significado está en el atributo. Pero en este caso el predicado está claramente en el verbo (el "mostrar semejanza"), mientras que el "yo" indica aquello a lo cual el sujeto se asemeja, algo mucho más cercano a un complemento directo que a un atributo.

Entonces creo que "parece yo" sirve como chiste. Se enuncia una construcción sintáctica correcta pero que no tiene correlación con aquello que se está queriendo dar a entender.

Comment: Buena respuesta, Rodrigo. Así y todo, quien dijo la frase "Parece yo" quería decir algo más que "Se parece a mí", algo así como el verse reflejado en el  espejo que menciona greuze: "Ése parece/parezco yo."

Comment: Realmente es una respuesta completa, pero me suscita una duda: ¿realmente "_yo_" puede funcionar como atributo? A no ser que se intentara hacer algo como un juego de palabras, como dices en la respuesta, lo veo un poco por los pelos. Incluso con el juego de palabras, no es que "_yo_" sea fácilmente reconocible como "_que indica la acción o el estado del sujeto_"... podría esperarlo en un libro de filosofía o psicoanálisis(es decir, dónde ese "_yo_" es algo diferente a un pronombre que designa una persona), no en una conversación normal sobre temas más mundanos.

Answer (score 2):

Yo diría que aparte de inusual (que lo es), también es incorrecto, intento explicar por qué.

En un caso análogo, cuando te ves a ti mismo en una foto, dices `este soy yo`, y no `este es yo`. Si no tuvieras la certeza total de la persona de la foto, podrías decir `este parezco yo`, pero no `este parece yo`, que es lo que dijo tu familiar.

Comment: Buena analogía, que explicaría el "Parezco yo" de mi pregunta. El verse en una foto me recuerda que las oraciones copulativas suelen ser "espejo". Utilizando el ejemplo de Rodrigo, sujeto y atributo o predicativo subjetivo pueden alternarse, con apenas un cambio de énfasis (no de significado): Los culpables son ellos / Ellos son los culpables.

Answer (score 2):

Preguntada a la RAE en Twitter, su respuesta ha sido [la siguiente](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/837289882997370880):

> Es una construcción admisible en la lengua oral.

Imagino que en la lengua escrita se prefieren variaciones como *se parece a mí* o similares. Sin embargo, en contextos informales decir "parece yo" no es incorrecto.

Como la respuesta de la RAE pareció un poco laxa, DGaleano probó a insistir preguntando si incluso en la lengua oral es correcto además de admisible. [Su respuesta](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/837582800333258752):

> Se puede considerar correcto.

Comment: Que respuesta mas floja por parte de la RAE. Admisible es cualquier cosa. La pregunta es ¿Es correcto? ¿Si quiero hablar correctamente lo puedo decir?

Comment: @DGaleano de hecho si te fijas yo preguntaba precisamente eso: si era correcto. Ya veo que les has respondido, tengo curiosidad por ver qué dicen.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Gracias, Carlos, por haber hecho la consulta. Considerando que "parecer" es el único verbo copulativo que permite esta construcción: *A parece B*, la RAE debería tener algo regulado al respecto.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @Gustavson. La RAE debería tener una posición al respecto. Van varias horas desde que les pregunté en el Tweeter pero aún no responden.

Comment: La RAE contesta a mi tweet "Se puede considerar correcto." y nuevamente lo digo, _que respuesta tan floja_ La pregunta requería de una respuesta "Es correcto"/"No es correcto" y ellos responden "se puede considerar correcto".  Antes dijeron "admisible" y ahora dicen "posible" nunca han dicho "es".  No se si es que yo no hablo español o son los de la RAE.

Comment: https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/837582800333258752

Comment: @DGaleano no eres tú, a mí a veces me ha pasado también que en la respuesta se han ido un poco [por los cerros de Úbeda](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8O2f8Ks#0tRGnRf). Por no hablar de cuando Pérez-Reverte me dijo directamente que [les diera una colleja](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17172/12637).