# ¿Son las contracciones "del" y "al" obligatorias?

Tags: gramática, españa, contracciones

La expresiones "de el" y "a el" son contraíbles:

> "Él vino de el campo" -> "Él vino del campo"
>
> "Él se fue a el campo" -> "Él se fue al campo"

Con excepción de cuando "El" forma parte de un nombre propio.

> "Fui de visita a El Cairo"
>
> "He aquí el guión de El violinista en el tejado"

Mi pregunta es: ¿son estas contracciones **obligatorias**? ¿Sería escribir "Él vino de el salón" una falta gramatical?

Comment: Bastante relacionado: [¿Es correcto mantener “de” y “el” separados en algún caso?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17118/1674), especialmente [la respuesta de Carlos Alejo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17121/1674) donde cita: _Si en un enunciado coinciden dos secuencias consecutivas de la preposición y el artículo, se recomienda realizar la contracción solo en la segunda_.

Comment: He añadido la etiqueta "España" porque me interesa que la respuesta sea válida en España (¿según la RAE?). Menciones a su validez en otros paises hispanoparlantes son apreciadas, pero mencionar su validez (o no) en castellano es **requisito** / I added the "España" tag because I mean for it to valid in Spain. Mentioning it's validity in Spain is a **mandatory requiriment** for a valid answer.

Comment: Nótese de todos modos que lo indicado por la RAE aplica al español en general, no al español de España en particular.

Comment: @fedorqui nótese que aquella respuesta se basó en el DPD. En realidad la _Nueva gramática_ dice que eso era preferible en la lengua antigua (lo de _de el del_), pero que hoy no es necesario así que la doble contracción (_del del_) se considera correcta.

Answer (score 5):

En la *Nueva Gramática* tenemos la última referencia al respecto, a partir del [párrafo §14.3a y siguientes](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=pGLgjjgoXDWzXmgR). Recopilamos así los siguientes casos, aparte de los que comentas de títulos de obras y nombres propios:

- Casos en los que ambas palabras no estén en estricta adyacencia: si se interpone algún símbolo gráfico no se pueden contraer.

  > *Agregó que "segundo paso, sería apoyar a Portugal y a otros países, en la próxima VII Cumbre Iberoamericana, para que haya una referencia importante a (el caso de) Timor Oriental.*
  >   *En los círculos ajedrecísticos se recuerda lo que ha pasado a la leyenda bajo el nombre de "el escándalo de Lucerna".*
- En los textos clásicos y la lengua antigua se consideraba a veces preferible evitar la concurrencia de dos contracciones idénticas seguidas, aunque hoy día esta repetición se considera correcta.

  > *En este jardín estava, señor, a las tres y un quarto esperándote a que salgas de el del Duque.*

No se comenta ningún otro caso, luego en la práctica, siempre que haya un "de el" junto sin ningún otro signo gráfico de por medio, es obligatoria la contracción. A menos que, como quedó demostrado en la pregunta *[¿Es correcto mantener "de" y "el" separados en algún caso?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17118/12637)*, el artículo "el" comience una oración de relativo con consistencia propia. Aunque es extremadamente raro, se probó que es posible, e incluso [un académico de renombre nos avaló](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17172/12637) el uso separado.