# ¿"De el sistema" o "del sistema"?

Tags: preposiciones, artículos, contracciones

De las siguientes dos frases:

> Se necesita información adicional **de el** sistema

---

> Se necesita información adicional **del** sistema

¿Cuál es la que estaría correcta?

Comment: Encontramos un caso en que se mantenía separado: [¿Es correcto mantener “de” y “el” separados en algún caso?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17118/1674).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct one is

> Se necesita información adicional del sistema

*De+el* must always be contracted to *del*. The only exception is the case when *el* is part of a proper noun, such as in "Vengo de El Corte Inglés", where "El Corte Inglés" is the name of a well-known chain of department stores.