# ¿Es incorrecto el uso de "a el" en vez de "al"?

Tags: artículos, nombres-propios, contracciones

¿Es incorrecto no utilizar contracciones cuando sea posible? Por ejemplo, "a el auto", "de el comienzo", etc..

Si no lo es, la duda queda resuelta. Ahora bien, si lo es, me pregunto qué pasa en el siguiente caso.

Supongamos que quiero referirme a un nombre propio formado por un sustantivo y su artículo como, por ejemplo, "El bar de Pepe". Está claro que decir "Voy al "bar de Pepe"." cambia el nombre original del bar (ni siquiera sé si correspondería usar mayúscula en la "b"). ¿Puedo decir, entonces, "Voy a "El bar de Pepe"."?

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Es correcto mantener “de” y “el” separados en algún caso?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17118/1674)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El uso de contracciones se explica en el §14.3b y siguientes de la *Nueva Gramática de la Lengua Española* (NGLE).  En el [§14.3b](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SncECaEzzDkNNWER) se dice que "su uso es general y se produce sistemáticamente en todos los contextos", salvo en las excepciones indicadas en los apartados siguientes. En el [§14.3c](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wucPmqbOOSdflJkR), se indica que, efectivamente, los nombres propios son **una excepción**. Uno de los ejemplos que pone la NGLE es

> Acaban de matar a Gaitán frente a El Gato Negro (García Márquez, *Vivir*).

En el §14.3c también se dice que, en la lengua hablada, sí que se suele producir la contracción, y por tanto hay algunos textos que reflejan este uso y utilizan la contracción también por escrito. La NGLE pone este ejemplo:

> Mañana voy a ir al Retiro.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y las referencias. Las tendré en cuenta.