# Transliteración del apellido ruso, Волков

Tags: traducción, pronunciación, nombres-propios, extranjerismos, transliteración

[Волков](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volkov_%28surname%29) es un apellido ruso que en las letras latinas se ha escrito en varias formas. Una que parece ocuparse hoy día en varios idiomas es Volkov, y otra que yo sé que se ha usado en español, pero hace siglos, es Bolcof. Desconozco la razón de escoger entre B & V, y entre C & K. Tampoco me queda claro el último fonema.

¿Cuál es la mejor manera de escribir Волков segun la fonética española?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple vista a mí me sale decir ***Volkov*** o ***Vólkov***.

Justifiquémoslo: en [Romanización del ruso](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanizaci%C3%B3n_del_ruso) tenemos una tabla de transliteración fonética del español. Tal y como comentan:

> La Asociación Española de Profesores de Lengua Rusa estableció unas normas de transliteración del ruso al castellano, las cuales más tarde adoptó el Servicio de Traducción Española del Parlamento Europeo, lo que se encuentra en sus boletines terminológicos y normativos, concretamente en el Boletín 74 del 2 de enero de 2005.1

Lo cual representa un gran alivio y es un recurso que me alegra sobremanera descubrir, pues años ha estuve batallando con casos similares y no descubrí esta biyección.

Buscando las letras de *Волков* nos encontramos con la tabla:

> | Letra rusa | Letra(s) española(s) | Caso | Ejemplo |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | В, в | v | todos los casos | Павлов = Pávlov |
> | К, к | k | todos los casos | Кольцо = Koltsó |
> | Л, л | l | todos los casos | Малевич = Malévich |
> | О, о | o | todos los casos | Волга = Volga |

Por lo que se confirma que es Volkov.

A la hora de decidir entre Vólkov y Volkov, parece que debemos optar por **Vólkov**, con tilde, pues [oigo en Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#ru/en/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2) que se pronuncia con la primera *o* tónica. ¿Y por qué lo escribimos con tilde? Porque [*las transcripciones de palabras procedentes de lenguas que utilizan alfabetos no latinos, incluidos los nombres propios, se consideran adaptaciones y deben seguir, por tanto, las reglas de acentuación*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16917/1674).

Comment: Sé que estoy siendo quisquilloso, pero no es una biyección. Como sabrás, una biyección debe ser inyectiva: a cada elemento de la imagen de la función en el segundo conjunto debe corresponder, como máximo, un elemento del primer conjunto. Pero esta condición no se cumple, ya que *i* corresponde tanto a И como a Й. Además, debe ser suryectiva: cada elemento del segundo conjunto debe corresponder a un elemento del primero, como mínimo. Pero "c", "h", "q", "w", "x"  no corresponden a ninguna letra cirílica.

Comment: @Obie2.0 gracias, lo sé. Diría que por suerte las grafías entre idiomas no son biyecciones, si no sería un poco aburrido. Hay letras que tienen más de una posibilidad y otras que no tienen ninguna. Sin embargo, mencioné lo de _biyección_ en mi respuesta pues en su momento aprendí un poco de ruso y en las primeras clases deseaba encontrar algo así como la piedra filosofal de correspondencias uno a uno entre el castellano y el ruso. Una biyección, vaya. Pero luego vi, como bien comentas, que no existe. Cómo no olvidar la impronunciable _Я_...

Answer (score 5):

En ruso es Во́лков. El acento gráfico no existe ahí; es una mera guía para saber qué sílaba se acentúa. Pero nosotros sí tenemos acento. Entonces, definitivamente es **Vólkov** (con tilde). El acento en ruso está en la primera sílaba y éste debe conservarse. Si se transliterase *Volkov*, la ausencia de tilde implica la acentuación aguda.

Sobre la *B* y *V* inicial ya ha comentado la otra respuesta. *V* es lo más cercano a la letra labiodental rusa *В* (mayúscula). La *be alta* en ruso se escribe *Б*. Transliterar como *Bolkov*, en teoría, no tiene concecuencias fonéticas trágicas, pero sugiere que el apellido ruso es *Болков*.

Comment: En algunos lugares donde sí se distingue entre _b_ y _v_ ([si es que los hay](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/19254/1674)), el uso de _Болков_ produciría un cierto cambio en la fonética. Pero nada trágico, como dices.

Comment: Gracias por el dato.

Answer (score 3):

Sobre el último fonema. Algunas letras rusas varían su valor en función de su posición. La letra rusa B, que se pronuncia /v/, al final de sílaba se pronuncia */f/*. La transliteración es la misma, V.

[https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/В](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92)

Comment: Esto explica mucho, yo no sabia del cambio fonico ahi. Me parece que la norma es deletrearlo segun la forma escrita del idioma de origen (Volkov), no segun su sonido en ese idioma (Volkof).